# Alfresco scoped webscript configuration, can it be loaded into an E4X object?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, e4x

I'm looking to use a scoped configuration file in an Alfresco javascript webscript. I started with this [wiki page](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts#Global_and_Scoped_Config), and it got me mostly there.

This [jira page](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-2613) told me I needed to create a file spring-webscripts-config-custom.xml and place it in a META-INF folder i.e. in /shared/classes/META-INF/spring-webscripts-config-custom.xml. Fine. Got that working. I can load the file, and browse the configuration using the methods listed in the Jira page.

But those methods are a pain to use (childrenMap and getChild), and I'd rather use E4X to parse and query the XML configuration file. To do so, I'd need to get the configuration file as a string and pass it to

var conf = new XML( configStr );

Any ideas on how I can do this?

And a good [E4X tutorial page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X)

Answer (score 2):

There's IMHO no way to achieve what you describe with a JS backed webscript. You would need to implement a [Java controller](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples) to get access to the configuration file and send it back to the client.

That said, exposing their content to the outside world it's not really what the Alfresco configuration files are designed for. If you could disclose more details of you are trying to achieve it would be easier to suggest some proper ways to expose configuration data to the client.

---

EDIT

After the scope has been clarified, my suggestion is to provide your web script with a dedicated XML configuration file containing all the mapping between error codes and messages. As explained in the [docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/ws-config.html), let's suppose your web script is defined in `myscript.get.desc.xml`. Then you can create a file named `myscript.get.config.xml` that contains e.g.:

```
<messages>
  <message>
    <id>1</id>
    <desc>A long description here</desc>
  </message>
</messages>
```

You can then parse such configuration in the JS controller `myscript.get.js`:

```
var myconfig = new XML(config.script);
```

Comment: I'm trying to put error codes & messages in a configuration file, so they are easily changed without changing code. A system the webscript communicates with returns an error code, the Alfresco webscript looks up the error code in the configuration file to get the message and reports both to the caller. I currently have the code working, but it's a royal pain in the butt to parse the configuration and loop through everything looking for a specific XML attribute. E4X would be much easier.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that in the documentation. But I need to get the error configuration from all of my web scripts, not just one. That's why I wanted to use the scoped configuration.